# How I can use UTF8 in PDO PHP, whe I want display my result?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=leonzemaim', 'leonzemaim', 'leonzemaim');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Orders');
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Hi. I try get my result in utf8 code?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `;charset=utf8` to your connection string.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=leonzemaim;charset=utf8', 'leonzemaim', 'leonzemaim');
```

Comment: It's not working for me...

Comment: Is the collation of your orders table utf8? Are you setting the correct charset when displaying the data? Also take a look at [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).